# how to add numbering to subsubsection-level headers in a chapter?

Tags: numbering

I am a beginner latex user,  I wonder if you could help me to add subsubsection level 1.1.1.1 in my report,
the code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{the name of chapter}
 \section{section test}
 \subsection{subsection test}
 \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
 \end{document} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter `secnumdepth` controls how many section levels are numbered:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

% -1: part
%  0: chapter
%  1: section
%  2: subsection
%  3: subsubsection
%  4: paragraph
%  5: subparagraph
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{the name of chapter}
  \section{section test}
  \subsection{subsection test}
  \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]